# How can I send variable from angular TypeScript to local API server?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular application that will upload files and within the application I have a variable called `property.name` and I would like to send this variable to my API server which is node.js

My upload TypeScript in angular:

```
onImageUpload1() {

    const imageForm = new FormData();
    imageForm.append('image', this.imageObj);
    this.imageUploadService.imageUpload(imageForm).subscribe((res:any) => {
      this.imageUrl = res['image'];
    });
```

My upload service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

imageUpload(imageForm: FormData) {
  console.log('image uploading');
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload/', imageForm);
 }
}
```

My variable is in a different TypeScript file called add property and there I have the variable `property.Name`.

I tried to do the following but it is not getting any log:

in my TypeScript file:

```
public data="test";
this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload/",this.data).subscribe();
```

and in the server.js:

```
var app2 = express();
app2.post('/api/v1/upload', function(req, res, next){
var data = req.body;
console.log(data);
});
```

but I am not getting any error and I am not getting anything in console.

Comment: i tried this but i am getting 2 values: 
test:Array<string> = ["cool"];
public data = {1:this.test};

in the api i have this:
app.post('/api/v1/upload', upload.array('image', 1), (req, res) => {
  /* This will be the response sent from the backend to the frontend */

  data = req.body;
  console.log(data);
 });

why I am getting 2 values (cool and undefined)?